# JPA 2.0 : Issue : orphanRemoval throwing integrity violations using Open JPA

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

Request assistance with the strange issue of cascade removal with JPA 2.0.Please find below the details
I'm using JPA bundled with IBM Websphere 8.5 that comes along with RAD.
The issue I'm facing is when I try deleting an entity having a one to Many relationships with another entity, I always encounter the ORA-02292: integrity constraint violation. Below are the specific parts highlighting the relationship between two entities - FeeForService and FeeForServiceProduct.
FeeForService has a One to Many Relationship with FeeForServiceProduct. 
Please note the issue occurs when I run it on the Websphere server. I've tried running the below as a standalone program and it works with the workarounds of putting a cascade property at the many end and invoking em.remove() twice

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FEE_FOR_SERVICE")
public class FeeForService implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
....
....
//bi-directional many-to-one association to FeeForServiceProduct
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="feeForService",cascade={CascadeType.ALL},orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<FeeForServiceProduct> feeForServiceProducts;
....
```

}

```
@Entity
   @Table(name="FEE_FOR_SERVICE_PRODUCT")
   public class FeeForServiceProduct implements Serializable {
    ....
    ....
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to FeeForService
     @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
     @JoinColumn(name="FEE_FOR_SERVICE_ID")
     private FeeForService feeForService;
   }
```

Initially I had tried with only CASCADE=CASCADEType.ALL property but as it didn't work out had to use orphanRemoval.

The error that I receive is java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02292: integrity constraint  violated. Child Record found.

Below is the code sample I have used for deleting the FFS entity, assuming by setting orphanRemoval to true I don't have to explicitly delete the FFSProduct entity. But that doesn't seem to be working

```
 public void testDeleteFFS(){
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DummyTestService");
    EntityManager em=entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    long crVO=3658;
    List<FeeForService> ffsExisting=(List<FeeForService>) em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM  FeeForService  i INNER JOIN i.customerRequest u where u.customerRequestId="+crVO).getResultList();
    System.out.println("begin of delete");
    //for deleting child entity FFSProduct
    for(FeeForService ffsCandidate:ffsExisting){
        em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.remove(ffsCandidate);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    /*for deleting parent entity FFS as the FFSProduct entity was retained when a single for loop was used*/
    for(FeeForService ffsCandidate:ffsExisting){
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.remove(ffsCandidate);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    }       
     System.out.println("End of delete");
}
```

Is there any way with JPA 2.0 where I can delete all the dependent entities by only invoking a remove operation on the parent entity and if so,please point out where I'm going wrong as my understanding until now is that this must be possible by setting orphanRemoval to true on the owning entity.

Also please note that the Cascade = CascadeType.ALL was given at the FFS product or the many end of the relationship as the solution was not working without it.(as I mentioned at the top it strangely seems to work when running as a standalone)

My persistence.xml properties are as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="DummyTestService" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"  >
    <class>FeeForService</class>
    <class>FeeForServiceProduct</class>
    <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx"/>
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="xxxx"/>
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="xxxx"/>
      <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported" />
      <!--  <property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" value="true"/> -->
      <property name="openjpa.Log" value="File=D:\XXXX\JPAstandalonelog,DefaultLevel=WARN, Tool=INFO,SQL=TRACE"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It is hard to understand your code. I can see only `ffs`, `ffs`....`ffs`.

Comment: I don't know specifics of OpenJPA, but orphanRemoval is a JPA 2.1 feature, not available in 2.0. Maybe using 2.0 on your `persistence.xml` is forcing it into a compliance mode.